# How to select certain range of index in list of list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

The list of list that i have right now:

> > List = [['Numbes of event is 1', 'event time is: ', 2019, 12, 6, 8, 0, 54, ' ', 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812, 1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event'],['Numbes of event is 1', 'event time is: ', 2019, 12, 6, 8, 0, 54, ' ', 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812, 1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event'],['Numbes of event is 1', 'event time is: ', 2019, 12, 6, 8, 0, 54, ' ', 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812, 1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event'],['Numbes of event is 1', 'event time is: ', 2019, 12, 6, 8, 0, 54, ' ', 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812, 1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event']]

After removing the index 0-8 of all the list:

> > List = [[2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812, 1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event'],[2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812, 1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event'],[2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812, 1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event'],[2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812, 1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event']]

Comment: Naming a variable `List` is bad for two reasons: First, it goes against style conventions. Second, it’s dangerously close to the builtin function `list()`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to access an element, or a range of elements in a nested array, if that's the case, just use `List[x][y:]`. Where `x` references the outer list, and `y` references the inner list.

edit: If you're trying to access a range of elements in the outer list, but only return a single value in the inner list, for example, `List[1:8][2]`, this will not work. The best way I've found to do this is with list comprehension. So something like `[x[1] for x in List[1:8]]`

Answer (score 1):

Here we are

```
cleaned = [l[9:] for l in List]
```

A working example with extra check

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

List = [['Numbes of event is 1', 'event time is: ', 2019, 12, 6, 8, 0, 54, ' ', 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813,
         2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625,
         2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812, 1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
         0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event'],
        ['Numbes of event is 1', 'event time is: ', 2019, 12, 6, 8, 0, 54, ' ', 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813,
         2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625,
         2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812, 1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
         0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event'],
        ['Numbes of event is 1', 'event time is: ', 2019, 12, 6, 8, 0, 54, ' ', 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813,
         2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625,
         2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812, 1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
         0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event'],
        ['Numbes of event is 1', 'event time is: ', 2019, 12, 6, 8, 0, 54, ' ', 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813,
         2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625,
         2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812, 1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
         0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event']]

cleaned = [l[9:] for l in List]
# post-processed, sliced
pprint(cleaned)

# From the question output required
List2 = [[2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813,
          2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812,
          1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event'],
         [2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813,
          2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812,
          1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event'],
         [2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813,
          2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812,
          1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event'],
         [2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813, 2594.30004882813, 2595.89990234375, 2595.89990234375, 2594.30004882813,
          2592.60009765625, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2592.60009765625, 2594.30004882813, 2599.30004882812,
          1915.3000488281302, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'turn off event']]
pprint(json.dumps(List2) == json.dumps(cleaned))
```

The requested output is equal to the `cleaned` one

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are asking as your question is general, but to access a list of list, you can simply do this:

```
list[i][j]
```

where "i" is the list inside the list you want to access, and "j" the the element within the list inside the list.